# "shutdown now" or "shutdown -h now" to power off Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian

I'm new to Linux (using Raspbian) and Raspberry Pi, and I'm wondering which of the two commands mentioned in the title that I should use when powering off my Pi. I googled them but still don't really get the difference between the two, does it matter which one I use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try typing [`man shutdown`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown). The man pages give you a complete list of the options that a command can take, and an explanation of what they do. In the case of `-h`:

> -h  Requests that the system be either halted or powered off after it has been brought down, with the choice as to which left up to the
>   system.

The difference between including the `-h` option or not, is slight, and is irrelevant in this case, as you can't poweroff the Pi anyway, not without manually removing the USB power.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation is in `man shutdown`.<sup>1</sup>

```
-P, --poweroff
           Power-off the machine (the default).

[...]

-h
           Equivalent to --poweroff, unless --halt is specified.
```

Sometimes commands have redundant seeming switches like this because they must satisfy specifications for several different contexts.  Simple logic tells us that since `poweroff` is the default anyway, using `-h` is itself redundant (again, it exists to satisfy an external spec; some implementations of `shutdown` may not work this way by default, but all the ones that conform will implement `-h`).

Since the pi itself can't poweroff (it is either plugged in == on, or not), there is no point in using `poweroff`, but it won't cause any harm.  It may make a difference WRT the way the red LED blinks at the end (you could compare with `shutdown -H` to see). Note the major purpose of `shutdown` is to stop (halt) the OS from running.

So you can use either form.

---

<sup>1. This one is actually from Raspbian *jessie* and comes with systemd; it is slightly different from the shutdown in Raspbian wheezy (Greenonline's answer quotes that), which is an example of what I mention in the next paragraph about different implementations meeting the same specification.  The shutdown process is actually part of the [init system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init), which is SysV on wheezy and systemd on jessie.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I prefer

```
sudo halt
```

I can't remember why I chose this, but, for whatever reason, other commands cause problems. This works perfectly. To reboot:

```
sudo restart
```

Comment: If you perform just a `halt` it _could_ cause data loss. A much better practice would be `sudo sync;sync;halt`, as this synchronises the data storage (i.e hard disks, SD card), with any unwritten cached data still in memory, before halting the system.

Comment: @Greenonline, if you perform a `halt` *from runlevel 0 or 6*, it could cause data loss.  At any other runlevel, it's equivalent to `shutdown -h now`.

Comment: Why does users tends to ignore existence of "init" command on unix-like OSes? `init 0` to shutdown, `init 6` to restart

Comment: @Greenonline, @Mark, From now on I'll use `shutdown -h now`, didn't realise `halt` was dangerous!